# How do I check raw_input against a list of strings?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here's what I have at this point:

```
def checkPlayerCardInput(answer):
    while True:
        for x in range(len(player1Cards)):
            if answer.lower() == player1Cards[x]:
                return player1[x]
```

What I don't know is how to repeat the loop if the user misspells a word or enters something incorrect entirely?

In this scenario, `player1Cards` is equal to a list of 5 strings. I'm simply trying to match the `answer` (which is input previously by the user via `raw_input`) to one of those strings and `return` that answer (which, in this case, is the item from the `player1` list that contains the rest of the data for the "card" returned).

If the answer is incorrect, I would like the loop to start with a fresh raw_input answer from the user.

Comment: Why do you have two different structures with data, `player1` and `player1Cards`? If you explain what are you trying to do we might be able to help you with data structures.

Comment: Player1 contained lists for each card in the "hand". player1Cards was a list of strings matching the card "names" from each hand.
I realize now that I haven't structured my lists all that well, but I've been using this program as an exercise to go from simple online tutorials to actually making something that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
def checkPlayerCardInput(answer):
    while True:
        for x in range(len(player1Cards)):
            if answer.lower() == player1Cards[x]:
                return player1[x]
        answer = raw_input('incorrect answer!')
```

Comment: Yes. This works perfectly, actually. I did not realize that I could reassign the `answer` variable without causing an error in the loop. I will accept this when the time limit has run out.

Answer (score 4):

To check that an item is contained in a list use `in` operator. Like this:

```
if answer.lower() in player1CArds:
    #...
```

Use a `while` loop to keep asking for `raw_input` until you're given a string found in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The `else` keyword can be use in your case. Used in conjonction with `for`, the else clause is executed when the range was exhausted without exiting the loop (break or return) :

```
for x in range(len(player1Cards)):
        if answer.lower() == player1Cards[x]:
            return player1[x]
else:
    # Here, your user input matches nothing.
```

However, you can use the `in` keyword of `list`:

```
if answer.lower() in player1Cards:
    # equivalent to your for loop
```

Or the opposite, `not in`:

```
if answer.lower() not in player1Cards:
    # Typo, or the user inputed a non-existing card
```